# Access ViewController from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

My problem is the following,

In one of my `ViewControllers`, when the user taps a button , I register the device for notifications with this code.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Then, in the `AppDelegte`, there are two methods. One that receives the token and one that gets the error.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
```

And now comes the problem, in `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` I need to send the token to my server, and with it some data that the user has entered in the `View`, like its username.

How can I get this data?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `NSNotificationCenter` will serve you well here.  In your AppDelegate's `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`, do this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RegistrationReceived"
                                                    object:token];
```

And, in your controller's `viewDidLoad`,

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(updateRegistrationInfo:)
                                             name:@"RegistrationReceived" 
                                           object:nil];
```

Be sure to implement `-updateRegistrationInfo:` (or whatever you want to name it) to receive the `NSNotification` and the token, which is passed in as the argument.  Also, unregister for the notification when you no longer need it.

```
- (void)updateRegistrationInfo:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSString *myObject = [notification object];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can can add your `ViewController` as an instance variable to your `AppDelegate` class:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
@private // Instance variables

    UIWindow *mainWindow; // Main App Window

    UINavigationController *navigationController;

    UIViewController *someViewController;
}
```

And then add some methods to `someViewController` that returns your requested data.

You can assign someViewController in `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` of the `AppDelegate` class in this way:

```
someViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil]; 

navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:someViewController];
```

Comment: ok, but now.. how do I assign the ViewController to this variable?

Comment: This will work, but it's kind of a hack... you're going backwards, looking up to the top of your hierarchy when what you want to do is propagate a notification forward, down to a controller.  Check out `NSNotificationCenter`… I've provided some more detail in my answer to your question.